# CocoonJS app works in launcher but not compiled apk or ipa

Tags: box2d, cocoonjs

I have an app built with cocoonjs that works perfectly in the launcher app on both iOS and Android, but the compiled versions of both freeze after the launch screen.

After doing an adb logcat on Android I can see the error 'Box2d is not defined' crashing the app.

How do I 'define' Box2d on the compiled app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER: The Box2 extension had to be checked under Services > Configuration in your Project on the website. I signed up for a premium account trying to get this fixed, so I'm not sure if you have to be a premium user in order to get access to this extension.